# Lomuto Algorithim verification Test Case

Tags: python, list

I want to create a testing function in Python which if I pass the list and the index position, it should return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the number at that position is placed correctly as per `Lomuto algorithm`.

For example

`verify_partition([-2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 14, 10, 23], 5)`. In this case, it should tell if element at position 5 is positioned correctly or not after sorting.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: im strugling to create such function which can verify it :(

Comment: I know that all indices should be lower or equal to uptil the position and greater afterward, but Im not able to write the python

Comment: @Tomerikoo. I know, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't resist.

If only distinct elements:

```
def isplaced(a, i):
    return sum(1 for e in a if e < a[i]) == i
```

For non-unique elements, you need to count the repeats of `a[i]` too:

```
def isplaced(a, i):
    key = a[i]
    lt_count = le_count = 0
    for e in a:
        if e < key:
            lt_count += 1
        elif e <= key:
            le_count += 1
    return lt_count <= i < le_count
```

More succinctly:

```
def isplaced(a, i):
    return sum(1 for e in a if e < a[i]) <= i < sum(1 for e in a if e <= a[i])
```

Comment: Wow... Appriciated :)

Comment: I did, but I guess I have new account so it is not showing up